# How make apache redirect the user to some page when the requested page is not existing

Tags: apache

How make apache redirect the user to some page when the user ask for some page which does not exist on the server instead of showing NOT FOUND on the browser ?

For example when the user asks for

```
 www.example.com/some_inexistant_file.php
```

the file does not exist on the server so automaticly make the server redirect the user to

```
 www.example.com/apologize.php
```

for example is there some to do that ?

Comment: You could create a custom 404 page and embed code into the page that redirects to your destination, or you modify the htaccess and redirect every time they hit a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a `.htaccess` file in your root folder and add this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /apologize.php
```

`apologize.php` has to be in the same folder the `.htaccess` is.